# Python: how to speed up this function and make it more scalable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, matrix

I have the following function which accepts an indicator matrix of shape (20,000 x 20,000). And I have to run the function 20,000 x 20,000 = 400,000,000 times. Note that the `indicator_Matrix` has to be in the form of a pandas dataframe when passed as parameter into the function, as my actual problem's dataframe has timeIndex and integer columns but I have simplified this a bit for the sake of understanding the problem.

## Pandas Implementation

```
indicator_Matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,[20000,20000]))
def operations(indicator_Matrix):
   s = indicator_Matrix.sum(axis=1)
   d = indicator_Matrix.div(s,axis=0)
   res = d[d>0].mean(axis=0)
   return res.iloc[-1]
```

I tried to improve it by using `numpy` but it is still taking ages to run. I also tried `concurrent.future.ThreadPoolExecutor` but it still take a long time to run and not much improvement from list comprehension.

## Numpy Implementation

```
indicator_Matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,[20000,20000]))
def operations(indicator_Matrix):
   s = indicator_Matrix.to_numpy().sum(axis=1)
   d = (indicator_Matrix.to_numpy().T / s).T
   d = pd.DataFrame(d, index = indicator_Matrix.index, columns = indicator_Matrix.columns)
   res = d[d>0].mean(axis=0)
   return res.iloc[-1]

output = [operations(indicator_Matrix) for i in range(0,20000**2)]
```

Note that the reason I convert `d` to a dataframe again is because I need to obtain the column means and retain only the last column mean using `.iloc[-1]`. `d[d>0].mean(axis=0)` return column means, i.e.

```
2478    1.0
0       1.0
```

**Update:** I am still stuck in this problem. I wonder if using gpu packages like `cudf` and `CuPy` on my local desktop would make any difference.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I imagine in your actual scenario you're running this on 400,000,000 different dataframes, and doing the same one over and over again is just for illustration?

Comment: Yes the the dataframes will be different. The number of rows will always be 20,000 but the number of columns may vary but always <= 20,000 columns.

Comment: Did you try using Numba?

Comment: do you mind showing Numba as a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately Numba [doesn't support](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1269) the `axis` parameter to `mean` or `average` (or a bunch of other functions), which makes things tricky...

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you have, as input, 400,000,000 matrices, with  400,000,000 integers in each? That is over one exabyte of data! If a CPU running at 10 GHz (does not exist) handled one integer in each cycle, that would still take 6 months. What you need to do is figure out how to get the same results from less data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the answer of @CrazyChucky is correct, one can implement a faster **parallel Numba implementation**. The idea is to use plain loops and care about reading data the *contiguous* way. Reading data contiguously is important so to make the computation **cache-friendly**/memory-efficient. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(['(int_[:,:],)', '(int_[:,::1],)', '(int_[::1,:],)'], parallel=True)
def compute_fastest(matrix):
    n, m = matrix.shape
    sum_by_row = np.zeros(n, matrix.dtype)
    is_row_major = matrix.strides[0] >= matrix.strides[1]
    if is_row_major:
        for i in nb.prange(n):
            s = 0
            for j in range(m):
                s += matrix[i, j]
            sum_by_row[i] = s
    else:
        for chunk_id in nb.prange(0, (n+63)//64):
            start = chunk_id * 64
            end = min(start+64, n)
            for j in range(m):
                for i2 in range(start, end):
                    sum_by_row[i2] += matrix[i2, j]
    count = 0
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        value = matrix[i, -1] / sum_by_row[i]
        if value > 0:
            s += value
            count += 1
    return s / count

# output = [compute_fastest(indicator_Matrix.to_numpy()) for i in range(0,20000**2)]
```

Pandas dataframes can contain both row-major and column-major arrays. Regarding the memory layout, it is better to iterate over the rows or the column. This is why there is two implementations of the sum based on `is_row_major`. There is also 3 Numba signatures: one for row-major contiguous arrays, one for columns-major contiguous arrays and one for non-contiguous arrays. Numba will compile the 3 function variants and automatically pick the best one at runtime. The JIT-compiler of Numba can generate a faster implementation (eg. using SIMD instructions) when the input 2D array is known to be contiguous.

---

### Experimental Results

This computation is about **14.5 times faster** than `operations_simpler` on my i5-9600KF processor (6 cores). It still takes a lot of time but the computation is **memory-bound and nearly optimal** on my machine: it is bounded by the main-memory which has to be read:

```
On a 2000x2000 dataframe with 32-bit integers:
 - operations:           86.310       ms/iter
 - operations_simpler:    5.450       ms/iter
 - compute_fastest:       0.375       ms/iter
 - optimal:               0.345-0.370 ms/iter
```

If you want to get a faster code, then you need to use **more compact data types**. For example, a `uint8` data type is large enough to contain the values 0 and 1, and it is 4 times smaller in memory on Windows. This means the code can be up to 4 time faster in this case. The smaller the data type, the faster the program. One could even try to compact 8 columns in 1 using bit tweaks though it is generally significantly slower using Numba unless you have a lot of available cores.

---

### Notes & Discussion

The above code works only with uniformly-typed columns. If this is not the case, you can split the dataframe in multiple groups and convert each column group to Numpy array so to then call the Numba function (modified to support groups). Note the @CrazyChucky code has a similar issue: a dataframe column with mixed datatypes converted to a Numpy array results in an object-based Numpy array which is very inefficient (especially a row-major Numpy array).

Note that using a GPU will not make the computation faster unless the input dataframe is already stored in the GPU memory. Indeed, **CPU-GPU data transfers** are more expensive than just reading the RAM (due to the interconnect overhead which is generally a quite slow PCI one). Note that the GPU memory is quite limited compared to the CPU. If the target dataframe(s) do not need to be transferred, then using cudf is relatively simple and should give a small speed up. For a faster code, one need to implement a fast CUDA code but this is clearly far from being easy for dataframes with mixed dataype. In the end, the resulting speed up should be `main_ram_throughput / gpu_ram_througput` assuming there is no data transfer. Note that this factor is generally 5-12. Note also that CUDA and cudf require a Nvidia GPU.

Finally, reducing the input data size or just the amount of computation is certainly the best solution (as indicated in the comment by @zvone) since it is very computationally intensive.

Comment: When I try this I get `Only constant step size of 1 is supported for prange` from `nb.prange(0, n, 64)`. It's honestly odd that I can't seem to find this fact mentioned anywhere in the [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/prange.html), especially since its use is only really described as relative to `range`, which of course does. (I guess somehow your test data was row-major and mine is column-major?)

Comment: Indeed, I added `prange` quickly but it does not support a third parameter like `range` (sadly). Sorry for the issue. I fixed the code. Note that `pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,[20000,20000]))` generates a row-major dataframe while Pandas dataframes tends to be column-major when they are not initialized from a (row-major) Numpy array.

Comment: Interesting. That is how I initialized my test data. Perhaps it's something platform-specific? In any event, this is great! On my machine it's twice as fast as my code. Hopefully the asker can still find some way to reduce the computations required, because 112 days is still not terribly practical, but I doubt it could get much faster as currently specified.

Comment: Running 400_000_000 times the function on a large dataframe is very expensive indeed. Using a GPU and packing booleans in bytes (as proposed) can make the computation 10-60 times faster. Having more information about how the code is actually used should certainly help to find solutions to reduce the number of calls or even to improve the cache efficiency.

Answer (score 8):

You're doing some extra math you don't have to. In plain English, what you're doing is:

1. Summing each column
2. Turning the list of sums "sideways" and dividing each column by it
3. Taking the mean of each column, ignoring values ≤ 0
4. Returning only the rightmost mean

After step one, you no longer need anything but the rightmost column; you can ignore the other columns, only dividing and averaging the one whose result you care about. Changing your code accordingly:

```
def operations_simpler(indicator_matrix):
    sums = indicator_matrix.sum(axis=1)
    last_column = indicator_matrix.iloc[:, -1]
    divided = last_column / sums
    return divided[divided > 0].mean()
```

...yields the same result, and takes about a hundredth of the time. Extrapolating from shorter test runs, this cuts the time for 400,000,000 runs on my machine from about 114 years down to... about 324 days. Still not great. So far I've not managed to get it to run any faster by converting to NumPy, compiling with Numba, or employing multiprocessing, but I'll go ahead and post this for now in case it's helpful.

Note: You're unlikely to see any improvements with compute-heavy work like this from threading; if anything, you'd want to use multiprocessing. `concurrent.futures` offers executors for both. Threads are mostly useful to avoid waiting around for I/O.

Comment: i am trying to understand why do i only need the rightmost column and ignore the rest ? Indicator_matrix might not be a square matrix and it's not symmetrical.

Comment: @user1769197 Well, think about it backwards from the end. You ultimately need the last/rightmost mean. That mean is calculated from the rightmost column, after dividing it by the column sums. So at the begining, you need the sum of every column. But then you only need to divide the rightmost column by those sums, then average it (ignoring the zeros). That calculation is not affected by the other columns, so why bother multiplying and averaging all of them? (Edited answer a little bit to hopefully clarify.)

Comment: Note: I don't know what your data represents, what your algorithm is supposed to calculate, or if you implemented it correctly. All I can do is reason from the code you showed, and that code tosses out the vast majority of its calculations once it does them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me study it for a bit and come back.

Answer (score 1):

As per the previous answer you can use Numba or you can you two other alternatives such as Dask which is a distributed computing package, to parallelize your function's execution it can divide your data into smaller bits and distribute computing across many CPU cores or even numerous machines.

```
import dask.array as da

def operations(indicator_matrix):
   s = indicator_matrix.sum(axis=1)
   d = indicator_matrix.div(s, axis=0)
   res = d[d > 0].mean(axis=0)
   return res.iloc[-1]

indicator_matrix_dask = da.from_array(indicator_matrix, chunks=(1000, 1000))
output_dask = indicator_matrix_dask.map_blocks(operations, dtype=float)
output = output_dask.compute()
```

or you can use CuPy which uses GPU to increase your function excution

```
import cupy as cp

def operations(indicator_matrix):
   s = cp.sum(indicator_matrix, axis=1)
   d = cp.divide(indicator_matrix.T, s).T
   d = pd.DataFrame(d, index = indicator_matrix.index, columns = indicator_matrix.columns)
   res = d[d > 0].mean(axis=0)
   return res.iloc[-1]

indicator_matrix_cupy = cp.asarray(indicator_matrix)
output_cupy = operations(indicator_matrix_cupy)
output = cp.asnumpy(output_cupy)
```